# Display google calendar events authenticating as service account - Golang App

Tags: go, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

Within my Go app, currently running as localhost on my dev machine (ultimately on a Linode), I wish to simply display public Google Calendar events from a calendar in my own Google account. At the moment this only displays to console because I want to get it working in principle and I have this code in the index page handler of my app.

```
googleCalendar, err := calendar.NewService(r.Context(), option.WithCredentialsFile("./googleAuth.json"))
    if err != nil {
        app.errorLog.Println(w, err)
    }
    
    calEvents, err := googleCalendar.Events.List("primary").TimeMin(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)).MaxResults(5).Do()
    if err != nil {
        app.errorLog.Println(err)
    }
    
    if len(calEvents.Items) > 0 {
        for _, i := range calEvents.Items {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, i.Summary, " ", i.Start.DateTime)
        }
    } else {
        app.errorLog.Println("No calendar events to display")
    }
```

The only way I think to do this is to use a service account because I am not a G Workspace (GSuite) user (the app will finally run on a Linode), Oauth2 directly is overkill and likely not available in my circumstances anyhow. I have enabled Google calendar API in my Google Dev Console and setup a service account, created / downloaded a json key file (as in the code). I have added the service account email as a shared user to the necessary calendar. The code compiles and runs but I only get my "No calendar events to display" because 'Items' is empty (the calendar does have events). Is there more here that needs to be done ? How to fetch these calendar event ? thanks

Comment: Who owns the calendar in question? Does the service account some how have a calendar for it?

Comment: I own the calendar, it is in my Google account with my Gmail address as owner. The service account was created from my Google developer console, along with the required json key file, which is accessible by the app in its root on my development machine. The email address of the service account was added to the calendar as another user.

Comment: Is it shared as see all event details to the service account?

Comment: "Is it shared as see all event details to the service account?"... yes it is. It's probably something pretty basic, just can't see it yet.

Comment: I can also see from my Google Dev Console that from IAM &Admin > Service Account > Metrics that my requests are triggering activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution to this issue. The code I posted is all that's needed in this case BUT it's the use of the keyword "primary" which is not working. I do not know why, it should work according to the Google documentation. I simply substituted "primary" with the actual calendar ID (not the calendar name) and all my events displayed.